# BottomNavigationView : FrameLayout vs ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I am implementing a `BottomNavigationView` in my app, but no tutorial I've seen has made this clear.

Should I use

- a `FrameLayout` (like [here](http://www.androprogrammer.com/2016/12/bottom-navigation-view-with-fragments.html)), and have my fragments appear and disappear,
- or a `ViewPager` (like [here](http://droidmentor.com/bottomnavigationview-with-viewpager-android/)) with an Adapter, and have my fragments swipe like with a `TabLayout`?

What are the pros and cons of both methods (for `BottomNavigationView`, not in general of course, I can RTFM), and is there one Google or old wise programmers are recommending over the other (couldn't see one in [the doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html) though)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Should I use a FrameLayout (like here), and have my fragments appear and disappear, or a ViewPager (like here), and have my fragments swipe like with a TabLayout?

The former. [The material design specs expressly indicate that you should not swipe between bottom navigation](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior). (see "Scrolling").

Quote:

> Using swipe gestures on the content area does not navigate between views.

Comment: You're right ! But then you don't get the benefits of the adapter loading fragments efficiently. So the question goes on : shoudn't I use a `ViewPager` and disable animation ?

Comment: If you use the FrameLayout with fragment transactions, the system will manage killing / restoring the state of fragments, same as if you'd use the pager adapter. So, no, you shouldn't use a ViewPager as it doesn't give you anything in this case.